# Why can't I drill deep enough into my wall for wall anchors?

Tags: drywall, mounting, hanging, drywall-anchor

I am living in a condo and have a problem to put anchor in the wall (drywall? I don't know th exact type of the wall). when I drill it doesn't go deep enough to put anchor completely in, so it can't stand heavy items. How can I figure out this problem.
I have heavy items to hang.

Comment: You probably have a concrete wall with drywall hung on 3/4 inch lathes. You will need a hammer drill with a masonry bit that is sized to fit your anchors. Now you will be able to drill far enough into the wall to accept the full anchor. You could also look at the masonry screws which don't need an anchor. They just have a special sized masonry bit and then you drive the screw straight into the hole. They are sold under the brand name Tapcons.

Answer (score 2):

You may be trying to drill into a concrete or brick wall. you can remove some outlet covers (e.g., electric, cable) on that same wall to be able to get a peek inside and confirm.  It's also possible that you are drilling into a stud or even a fire break. Both of the above situations are a good thing if you are trying to hang/mount heavy items.

If it is a concrete wall, look into the correct [concrete wall anchor](https://www.google.com/search?q=concrete%20wall%20anchors&oq=concrete%20wall%20anchors&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.6873j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) for the weight or bolt size you need. You may also need to get a drill bit for concrete if you don't have one.

If it is a wood stud, you may not need to use a drywall anchor.